# In Jmeter before sending Http samplers I want to hit a URL to set some values, How do i do it?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, test-automation-framework

I have a Jmeter script ready for checking performance of webapp, Before i send the actual http request to measure performance, i want to send another http request to set some value. How do set the http request to set some values in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Normally people use [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) for any precondition actions.

If for some reason this is not applicable for your scenario - you can consider using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) API to send a custom HTTP Request prior to the JMeter's one. The time taken by PreProcessors, PostProcessors and Timers is not included into the sampler's "Elapsed Time".

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) for some reference Groovy code, but keep in mind you need PreProcessor, not the PostProcessor.